# Нужен совет от Unity-разработчиков

Tags: unity3d

Здравствуйте всем. Мне нужна помощь, или есть вопрос по Unity разработке. Недавно начал изучать Unity и сделал небольшой проект по дополненной реальности. Суть проекта состоит в том, чтобы когда камера видит букву на листке, то над листком появляется 3D объект. Сделал это на фреймворке Vuforia. У меня есть мысль чтобы расширить проект: когда допустим из этих букв на листе собрать какое-то слово, камера должна распознать слово и выдать это на экране, и приложение допустим могла бы искать в базе это слово и вернуть по этому модель/рисунок. Я прочитал про machine vision, и оно примерно подходит как решение. Какой алгоритм/технологию еще посоветуете?